# Create NFS server

Tags: server, windows-10, 16.10, nfs

I'm new to Ubuntu and want to make a NFS share with Ubuntu or Ubuntu server. I want to share files between my Ubuntu 16.10 computer and my Windows 10 computer. If its possible, I also want to reach the Share from the outside of my house. (Maybe a VPN or something like that)

Thanks for help!

Comment: First, split your two questions - Win 10 access and access from outside. Second, for Win 10 to access, don't use NFS (a Unix/Linux product that I would not trust Windows to support). Consider setting up a Samba service on the Ubuntu system.